ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpds.rpds'
I have been running jupyter lab in my virtual environment with no problem. But I installed another program which probably caused issues with launching jupyter lab this morning. I have tried to update jupyterlab but nothing changed. Here is the error code when I try to run jupyter lab. Does anyone have experience with this? What should I do? Thank you!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .handlers.announcements import (
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\announcements.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import APIHandler
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\base\handlers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from jupyter_events import EventLogger
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_events\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .logger import EVENTS_METADATA_VERSION, EventLogger
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_events\logger.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jsonschema import ValidationError
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jsonschema._format import FormatChecker
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import FormatError
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from referencing.exceptions import Unresolvable as _Unresolvable
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\referencing\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from referencing._core import Anchor, Registry, Resource, Specification
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\referencing\_core.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rpds import HashTrieMap, HashTrieSet, List
  File "C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\rpds\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rpds import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpds.rpds'

*UPDATE: I installed the rpds file, but now it is giving me the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'HashTrieMap' from 'rpds' (C:\Users\lixia\venv\Lib\site-packages\rpds_init_.py)

It should be py -m pip install rpds-py

rpds-py is there. requirements are satisfied.

If you accidentally installed py -m pip install rpds did you then uninstall rpds?  If not, you may be having a conflict due to both packages having the same name.  The rpds package is old (last update 2017)

pip uninstall rpds

pip uninstall rpds-py

pip install rpds

pip install rpds-py==0.18.1 

This works for me.

I did not specified version for the last installation btw so that it would install the newest version.

In case of using poetry, then simply:
poetry add rpds
Docs
